Can't import own pip packages via `pip install -e .`
I am developing a project and I have two project modules: A (main, private), B (library, maybe public in the future), and I've a package for each.
Now, I'm trying to create a dev pip install via pip install -e ., and also through pip install git+https://github.com/username/packagename
But when I try to import packagename into my python code neither worked.
Screenshot of an "Import "packagename" could not be resolved`
Execution was by-the-book like here: https://medium.com/@anjali.gaddam98/package-your-code-as-a-pip-module-mastering-python-3c9d90c5deb1
setup.py, __init__.py are, of course, present
I've tried to

Update packages to ensure that I use up-to-date versions of own packages

Check python path: output of python3 -m pip -V and pip -V is both pip 24.1.2 from /home/mriabov/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10) , so python is not an issue. Or is it? It's not usr/bin/pip. Or should it be usr/bin/pip?

Installing both the pip install -e ., and non- -e (non-dev install)

Installing from github and from local.

Restarting the PC to - just in case - apply linux changes.


I'm using vscode to execute my python files, but I see no reason in vscode possibly interfering. Vscode also runs
The setuptool of sub-module is attached below:
    setup(
        name="packagename",
        version="0.1.1",
        packages=find_packages(exclude=["tests*"]),
        install_requires=[
            'jax>=0.4.30',
        #     'dependency2>=2.1.0',
        ],
        author="Maksym Riabov",
        author_email="your.email@example.com",
        description="desc",
        # long_description=open('README.md').read(),
        # url="https://github.com/yourusername/your-repo",
        long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
        classifiers=[
            "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
            "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
            "Operating System :: OS Independent",
        ],
        python_requires='>=3.6',
    )

Additionally, checked sources:
This has solved a similar issue with a PYTHONPATH, but it's probably not a good solution, and won't work for end-user.
What am I missing?

are you sure that the interpreter you are installing your package to is the same interpreter that you are trying to actually use to run the code?
